# How to Scroll web page to the target element using selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scroll to an element in selenium, but I want it to be at the top of the page, not just visible on the page.

How can I make it so that the page scrolls such that the element being scrolled to is at the top of the browser?

```
target = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".answers-wrap")
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(target)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Sure, but unless you have a chegg account, you can't actually view the element with that class. https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/42-following-instance-knapsack-problem-knapsack-capacity-11-use-sahni-s-approximation-sche-q46619490

Comment: Have you tried with `target.location_once_scrolled_into_view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is example using this page we are on*

*To scroll the web page by 1000 pixel vertical use **`execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")`***

*Example*

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071131/'
                   'scroll-in-selenium-driver-to-make-element-at-top-of-the-page')
time.sleep(4)
''' execute_script("window.scrollBy(x-pixels,y-pixels)")
    scroll down the page by  1000 pixel vertical
'''
chrome_browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")
```

> **`execute_script("window.scrollBy(x-pixels,y-pixels)")`**
>
> <sub>*x-pixels is the number at x-axis, it moves to the left if number is positive and it move to the right if number is negative .y-pixels is the number at y-axis, it moves to the down if number is positive and it move to the up if number is in negative .*</sub>

---

*To scroll down the web page to the target element.*

> **`execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)`**
>
> *"arguments[0]" means first index of page starting at 0.*

*Code example*

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome_browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071131/'
                   'scroll-in-selenium-driver-to-make-element-at-top-of-the-page')
time.sleep(4)

element = chrome_browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "#footer > div > nav > div:nth-child(1) > h5 > a")

chrome_browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

---