# Python Selenium not scrolling to the bottom of the page

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a program that loads a webpage in Selenium and then scroll to the bottom of that page. Currently, my program can load the page but cannot scroll to the bottom of it. Below is my full code. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller


import time

mouse = Controller()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Brian\Downloads\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.tradingview.com/chart/lUsimB6z/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")






#open("source.html", "w").write(str(html))
```

Comment: It scrolls to the bottom for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071503/4539709

Comment: do you get error ? Did you try to sleep longer? Code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried below code and its workingf for me

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/lUsimB6z/")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

output:

[image]