# Scraping r/AskReddit headline h3's. Able to get few results. How do I get to the next page to get more?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, reddit

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/hot")

for record in soup.findAll('h3'):
    print(record.text)
```

Comment: Try using Reddit's API to get data about posts and such.

Comment: scroll the page - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071503/4539709

Comment: Buliding on @Holden 's answer, check out PRAW reddit API. Its pretty detailed and documentation is awesome.