# Python beautifulsoup loading more data

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When you scroll through a web page it loads more data. How do you get bs4 to load all of these data?

Comment: do you mean data loaded after initial page load by javascript?

Comment: use selenium - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071503/4539709

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful soup is a parser which parses the data you feed it. For loading whole data from a dynamic webpage, you can use selenium like [Selenium: Scroll to end of page in dynamically loading webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851166/7814637)

Comment: If you find that an answer to another question addresses the problem at hand, then flag the question as a duplicate. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) in the [help] for more information.